# How to redirect from loading page to mainpage using NodeJS and Express

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

So essentially what I want to do is to render my loading page and after a few seconds bring the user to the main site. I know that you can use `window.location.pathname` but I'm pretty sure that only works for html pages, and I'm using express which doesn't provide that. My thought process is to render the page using Express, that page will then make post request back to it's self, which will redirect to the main page. I'm relatively new to Express and NodeJS so please point me to any duplicates.

Node JS Code

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){ // render loading page
    res.render('loadingpage', res);
    console.log("before redirect");
});
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(301, '/chats');
});
```

JQuery Code (for loading page)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("loading page loaded.");
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/',
            success:function() {
                console.log("redirected.");
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not an answer but you could have a loader on the main page (while you wait for the backend response for example), once you have the response you just remove/hide the loader. So this would be only on the client side. I guess most sites do it like this. So unless you have specifics needs where a redirection is wanted, this might be the easiest

Comment: How would I do that? Because right now I just want to render the loading page for x amount of seconds and then move to the next page (i.e ```/chats```)?

Comment: Well with something like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5 (a search for "loader js" or "loader css" might yield results that better fits your needs tho) you could have the loader to spin for x seconds before actually rendering your page. I don't really see the point of setting a hard number of seconds since loaders are generally used to show the user that the page is waiting for something from the server (js/css files, API response, images...) so ideally an user with a good connection should have the loader less time than a user with a poor connection

Comment: Also there is no need for a POST request in this case, a GET request would be a better fit. But then again, I would not recommend a redirect (which indirectly means a reload) after the end of a loader, except if you have specials needs (and if that's the case those needs should be added to the question)

Comment: I mean the only thing I want to do is on visit of / the loading page will render and stay like that for a second or two and then load to /chats, where the main function of the webapp lies. As for the GET, you mean in GET in the JQuery or Node JS Code?

Comment: If I may ask why don't you use `/chats` as your homepage since coming from `/` will just do a redirect ? Anyway, nowadays when building a web app you should try to avoid refreshing the page so a redirect is certainly not the best.

Comment: I guess I could do that. I just kinda wanted to add more aesthetics to my site.